# If a random variable is independent from the two components of a random vector, are the random vector and the random variable independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

in my probability class I was asked this seemingly very tricky question dealing with random variables and vectors:

> Let $ X,Y,Z $ be random variables with PDFs (continuous) such that we know that Z and X are independent and the variables Z and Y are independent. We are asked to prove or disprove (give a counterexample) that the random vector $ (X,Y) $ and $ Z $ are independent.

I have tried to prove it just with the basic identities and definitions but got nothing so maybe it is false and we must give a counterexample? I do not even know how to deal with this, so I really need the help. Thanks all helpers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A counterexample is given by equal probabilities for $(X,Y,Z)$ to take the values $(0,0,0)$, $(0,1,1)$, $(1,1,0)$, $(1,0,1)$. Both $(X,Z)$ and $(Y,Z)$ have uniform distribution, so $X$ and $Z$ are independent and $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, but $(X,Y)$ is clearly not independent from $Z$ (in fact the value of $(X,Y)$ fixes the value of $Z$).

Comment: Thank you for your effort and a nice answer but I do not quite understand as your example seems discrete and I was going for something continuous and also I don't understand quite clearly the meaning of X,Y,Z in your example and the uniformity you mention.

Comment: @AbeerAbassi: Sorry, I missed the continuous part, but you can easily make them continuous, e.g. replace $0$ and $1$ by uniform distributions over $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$, respectively. I'm not sure what you mean by "the meaning of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$" -- what exactly is it about them that you don't understand?

Comment: Thanks now I understand the principle but could you please go the one step further and show me explicitly what you mean and how to justify the steps?

Comment: @AbeerAbassi: It's hard to respond to that request without knowing which parts don't strike you as explicit enough.

Comment: Well I do not understand how to define the vector $ (X,Y,Z) $ in terms of continuous uniform distributions

Comment: @AbeerAbassi: Replace $0$ and $1$ in my example by uniform distributions over $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$, respectively; that is, define $(X,Y,Z)$ such that there are equal probabilities for $(X,Y,Z)$ to lie in $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,1]$, $[0,1]\times[1,2]\times[1,2]$, $[1,2]\times[1,2]\times[0,1]$ and $[1,2]\times[0,1]\times[1,2]$, with values within the intervals distributed uniformly.

Comment: Ok I understand this almost, except how do we now justify the dependence and independence as mentioned?

Comment: @AbeerAbassi: Which part is unclear -- why they hold in the original example, or why this transfers to the continuous example? You really should put more effort into formulating precise questions; the way you're asking, you're putting the entire onus on the respondent to explain whatever might be explained, which is a lot more work than explaining specific points.

Comment: I am sorry I get it now and I thank you

Answer (score 2):

Another example: Toss a fair die twice. Let $X$ be the number showing on the first toss, and $Y$ the number showing on the second toss. Let $Z$ be the indicator of the event that $X+Y$ is even. Then $X$ and $Z$ are independent, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, but $Z$ is clearly a non-random function of $(X,Y)$ and so $Z$ is not independent of $(X,Y)$.